# jQueryMobile Datebox/ASP.NET MVC data-ajax=false script not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, jquery-mobile, razor, datebox

I've got a little problem: I have an Edit View with this time-picker inside

```
<label for="mytimeedit">Time</label>
    <input name="Time" id="mytimeedit" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "overrideTimeFormat": 24}'>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Time)
```

Then (in the same view) I have this script to replace every ":" character inserted on the early described text input with a comma (","):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#mytimeedit").change(function () {
    var val = $("#mytimeedit").val();
    $("#mytimeedit").val(val.replace(':', ','));
});
</script>
```

Everything worked, until I had to insert a **data-ajax=false** attribute (and I cannot remove it, for the consistency of my site) in the link calling the Edit controller: this way the replacing doesn't work anymore.

My question is: is there a way to "translate"/rewrite my script avoiding Ajax, which is now disabled?

Hope for your help,thanks!